# mongodb import error. My mongodb document created only id after npm run data:import

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, data-import

here is my model below

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({
name: {
type: String
},
description: {
type: String
},
price: {
type: Number
},
countInStock: {
type: Number
},
imageUrl: {
type: String,
}
});

module.exports  = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema );

Comment: I don't think the error has much to do with the code. Can you include more details please? What is `npm run data:import` doing?

Comment: it import already created data (data.js) from your file in root directory in JSON format to your mongodb database automatically

Comment: You need to include what db command it is exactly running and the full error output.